# Append to array in Mongoose populate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  body: {type: String, required: true, max: 2000},
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  flags: {type: Number, default: 0},
  fileName: {type: String, default: ""}
}, {
  writeConcern: {
    w: 0,
    j: false,
    wtimeout: 200
  }  
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
  body: {type: String, required: true, max: 2000},
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  flags: {type: Number, default: 0},
  fileName: {type: String, default: ""},
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
}, {
  writeConcern: {
    w: 0,
    j: false,
    wtimeout: 200
  }  
});

var Post =  mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema)

module.exports = {
  Post: Post,
  Comment: Comment
}
```

I want to be able to append a comment to the comment array in post using the populate method, but I've looked through a lot
of examples online and I haven't found a simple method. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please can you give an example of your use case its not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Odds are you confusing terms here and all you really want to do is "insert documents into the referenced collection". These are separate documents in separate collections, so it's **two** writes and *not one*. Basically insert into the other collection and then "push" the result `_id` value into the master document array. Really, keeping an "array of refs" is an "anti-pattern" and is merely historically referenced as a "hacky" way mongoose originally implemented "join emulation".